# Egg shells speckled after cooking

Tags: eggs

[image]

I made some boiled eggs and they were white when they went in! I did water, two inches above the eggs (18 of them). 1/3c Apple cider vinegar, and 1T salt... I was using a cheap Walmart pan as we just moved and I bought it for like $5. It’s really thin. I brought to a boil and then cooked for 11-12 mins.

Comment: Why did you use vinegar ?

Comment: Hi! This is interesting, and you have an upvote from me, I also want to know what it was :) On our site, it is important that a question serves not only the person asking, but also others who face similar problems. So I changed the title of your question to be a concrete description of the problem - with the old title, it wouldn't be come up during relevant searches.

Comment: @Max I've heard some tales that vinegar helps with peeling afterwards... but I think it's patently false. With that said, the black spots could be flecks of a non-stick coating coming off. Especially since if you zoom in on the image, some of the eggs look "dirty".

Comment: Neither vinegar nor salt should cross the shell, both are totally useless.  The age of the egg has more to do with the pealability, with fresher eggs noticeably harder to peel.

Comment: @GeorgeM why shouldn't they cross the shell? For example, the acid based dyes for Easter eggs cross the shell easily. I think there is a fair chance that the vinegar will cross the shell too. Besides, "easier for peeling" doesn't necessitate crossing the shell, it could just make it more brittle from the outside.  I don't know if they actually help, but the assumption that they couldn't possibly help seems unfounded.

Comment: Addendum: since I found it interesting to know if the salt-and-vinegar tale is true or not, I asked a question on it: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94689

Answer (score 1):

As you posted a high-res picture, I can clearly see that this is exactly like my grandmother's white eggs would look like after she boiled them in an aluminium kettle.  AFAIK they don't sell these any more, so I'm surprised to see eggs like this again after 30 years.

After peeling, the discolouration wasn't noticeable any more.

If both assumptions above (Aluminium pot and not visible any more after peeling) they are safe to eat as Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> is probably the root cause and it's safe according to [this document](https://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/aluminium_summary_statement.doc) published by the WHO.